# accessing file from a folder in php

Tags: php

In php, I have a form where user can view comments by clicking on a button

```
echo "<td> <form action=\"viewComments.php?id=$pid\" method=\"post\">";
```

This works fine when I put viewComments.php in the same folder. I want to organise my code and put viewComments.php in a folder lets say "actions". How do I do this? In other words, if I want to access "viewComments.php" that is in a folder called 'actions' how to reflect that in here?
    echo " ";
Can somebody help?

I have
blog_created/thisScript.php - Here I have my code and my viewComments.php is in blog_created/actions/viewComments.php... It's not working.... It is saying - The requested URL /~user/blog_created/viewComments.php was not found on this server

Comment: Just add `actions/` in front of `viewComments.php`?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td> <form action=\"actions/viewComments.php?id=$pid\" method=\"post\">";
```

is this want you to achieve?